# Flow based programming js html ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, dom-events

I need your great help on how to create a Simple Flow based UI in JS.

For my simple structure I will have 3 node groups that will connect like so :

Input -> Process -> output

For the below example I would like to just start of with a static input value of x=65 that can be connected via a connector to a process of either x+10   or x+10000 and depending on which ever is selected  the out put is shown.

So its basically a function:

```
function input(){
x=65;
return x;
}

function processadd10(x){
x=x+10;
return x;
}

function processadd10000(x){
x=x+10000;
return x;
}

function output(x){
return "after processing the value of X is".X;
}
```

The part I need help with is how can I implement a flow based User  interface where I can drag and connect the relevant boxes to create an output..

I would appreciate any help in building a simple UI to do the below .

[image: Intended example interface]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **jsplumb toolkit** for the same.

It allows you to build application with **visual connectivity** fast. It has support for drag n drop, connecting two nodes, pan and zoom feature, mini map etc

Jsplumb toolkit website is at  [link](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com).

Go through their demos and you will be convinced that you are looking for the same

Comment: can you give example  how to make above?

Comment: Go through their documentation. They have lots of example for the same.

Answer (score 0):

JSPlumb seems to cost $3000 for one developer license! Here's a free, open-source library that I found that's only 10kb gzipped: https://github.com/shamansir/rpd

[image]

[image]

[image]

And Total.js seems to have [a library for flow-based stuff](https://www.totaljs.com/flow/) (also free):

[image]